# Folder is invisible in Site.master ,when using href?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

Given this Site.master  :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SiteMaster" Codebehind="Site.master.cs" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1>
                            My ASP.NET Application
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="loginDisplay">
                        <asp:Panel ID="panelLogin" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="panelLogout" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            Welcome <span class="bold">  <asp:Literal ID="LoginName" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>!
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogout" runat="server" onclick="lnkLogout_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Items>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                            </Items>
                        </asp:Menu>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run my app (web app) , I get here :

[image]

When I hit login , I reach here

[image]

It seems that `Site.master` can't see the `Login.aspx`  .

But when I place `Login.aspx` outside of the `Account` folder , it works OK  , meaning doing this :

```
<a href="~/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
```

Any idea how to fix the visibility ?

Here is the hierarchy

[image]

Answer (score -1):

check the folder for login..
it is not `~/login.aspx` but `~/Account/login.aspx`